# Explanation for strange peak in weak scaling plot

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, scalability, hpc

I'm running a simple kernel which adds two 3rd order tensors of double-precision complex-values. I've parallelized it using OpenMP with custom scheduling: the `slice_indices` container contains different indices for different threads.

```
    for (const auto& index : slice_indices)
    {
        auto* tens1_data_stream = tens1.get_slice_data(index);
        const auto* tens2_data_stream = tens2.get_slice_data(index);
        #pragma omp simd safelen(8)
        for (auto d_index = std::size_t{}; d_index < tens1.get_slice_size(); ++d_index)
        {
            tens1_data_stream[d_index].real += tens2_data_stream[d_index].real;
            tens1_data_stream[d_index].imag += tens2_data_stream[d_index].imag;
        }
    }
```

The target computer has a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU with

1. 24 cores @ 2.70 GHz,
2. L1 cache 32 kB, L2 cache 1 MB and L3 cache 33 MB,
3. the memory bandwidth is 115 GB/s (source: Intel Advisor's roofline plot).

Now the weak scaling plot:
[image]

**Notes:**

1. In the above, if `N=90` then the data-size is `90*90*90*16` = 11,1237 MB.
2. The sizes of the cache in terms of problem size are L1 ~ 12, L2 ~ 40 and L3 ~ 129.

**Question 1**: why is there an unexpected peak at N=90? In fact, why isn't the whole plot just a simple straight line?

If you suspect cache-effects, I would be grateful if you could explain in more detail.

I can provide more information if necessary. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here's a weak-scaling plot with finer resolution:
[image]

And here's a problem scaling plot with only 1 thread:
[image]

**Question 2**: If I am initializing my data by *only touching the first entry of each memory page* i.e. my data has not been loaded to cache yet, why am I seeing the typical stepped performance graph?

Comment: Is the issue reproducible?

Comment: Yes, I've let the program run multiple times for the case N=90 with 6 threads.

Comment: Could you help me go through the calculation? I simply expect a straight line.

Comment: Your L2 cache is 1M per core, not? That means that 6x might be the largest problem that fits in L2. I suggest you try a bunch of intermediate sizes. Your problem probably never fits in L1, so maybe this is just the ramp up to maximum L2 usage before it drops to memory bandwidth.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Why is that stepped cache-based pattern expected? Isn't it so that streaming is cache-independent? Or is this a product of loop-unrolling and prefetching?

Comment: If your whole dataset fits in cache, then initialization will place it there, and operating on it will be streaming from cache. It depends on the structure of your code.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout ah yes now i follow you. That's in case of a "hot run". I time "cold runs" i.e. I initialize by touching only the first data-point of each memory page to prevent page faults. This means the majority of the data is not yet in cache during the run.

Comment: I suggest you use a low level tool such as VTune or PAPI to measure cache misses and such. Did you follow up on my suggestion of trying some more intermediate sizes? Your graph is very coarse. Btw, if you initialize only the first element of each page, you basically operate on random junk data. Correct?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yes, I operate on garbage values.

Comment: Could you label your graphs with dataset size in Mb? That way it's easier to relate to cache phenomena.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I've updated the plots.